# Android webview url won't load

Tags: android, webview, web

simple problem. I am using webview to show a page where I have photos. The problem is that when I use an intent with website which I use, it just shows me a blank page. I don't know where is the problem, because when I use this site on browser it works. So here is a solution that I use

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    themeInfo = getSharedPreferences("THEMECONFIG",0);
    themeSetting = themeInfo.getString("theme","Základná");
    processer = new ProcessFunction();
        try {
            ConnectivityManager con = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo net = con.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            String web;
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (net != null && net.isConnected()) {
                if (processer.isOnline()) {



                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);




                    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                    drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                            fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_left));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                            fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_right));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

                        }
                    });
                    toggle.syncState();
                    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
                    processer = new ProcessFunction();
                    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                    MultiTouchListener touchListener=new MultiTouchListener(this);
                    fab.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
                    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            if(!drawer.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START))
                            {
                                drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                                fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_left));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_right));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("website") == null) {
                        web = "http://www.lodkanadeje.maweb.eu/";
                    } else {
                        web = getIntent().getStringExtra("website");
                    }
                    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webb);

                    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                    progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.LTGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    progressBar.setScaleY(0.1f);
                    progressBar.setScaleX(0.1f);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                    wv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
                    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });

                    wv.loadUrl(web);

                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Hups, niečo je zle :(")
                            .setMessage("Internet nie je dostupný")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                            })
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .show();

                }

                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

                Button buttonSettings = (Button) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.button_settings);
                buttonSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings_activity.class);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

                    }
                });

                if(!themeSetting.equals(themeInfo)) {
                    if (themeSetting.equals("Základná")) {
                        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                        processer.changeTheme("Základná", checker, MainActivity.this, navigationView, drawer);
                        checker = true;
                    }
                    if (themeSetting.equals("Matrix")) {
                        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeMatrixDivider);
                        processer.changeTheme("Matrix", checker, MainActivity.this, navigationView, drawer);
                        checker = true;
                    }
                    if (themeSetting.equals("Gamers")) {
                        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeGamersDivider);
                        processer.changeTheme("Gamers", checker, MainActivity.this, navigationView, drawer);
                        checker = true;
                    }
                }

            } else
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Hups, niečo je zle :(")
                        .setMessage("Chýba pripojenie k internetu. Zapnite prosím dáta alebo Wi-Fi a spustite aplikáciu znova.")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
            }




        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("chyba", e.getMessage());
        }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    Button sett = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_settings);
    TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(MainActivity.this, themeInfo.getInt("setItemIconTintList",R.drawable.menu_text_color_normal) ));
    navigationView.setItemTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(MainActivity.this, themeInfo.getInt("setItemTextColor",R.drawable.menu_text_color_normal) ));
    navigationView.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, themeInfo.getInt("setBackgroundDrawable",R.drawable.border_top_bottom_normal) ));
    sett.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(MainActivity.this, themeInfo.getInt("settSetTextColor",R.color.colorWhite) ));
    text.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(MainActivity.this, themeInfo.getInt("textSetTextColor",R.color.colorDefault) ));
    toolbar.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, themeInfo.getInt("toolbarSetBackground",R.color.colorPrimary) ));
    toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(themeInfo.getInt("toolbarGetNavigationIcon()",R.color.colorWhite)), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    fab.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(MainActivity.this, themeInfo.getInt("fabBackground",R.color.colorPrimary)));
    }
```

And here is a function where I choose what to do in intent

```
public void MenuProcessing(int id, final Activity context, ProcessFunction processer)
{
    if (id == R.id.nav_domov) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("website","http://lodkanadeje.maweb.eu/");
        context.startActivity(myIntent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        String s = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=redacted";
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("website",s);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_facebook) {
        processer.SharingToSocialMedia("com.facebook.katana", context);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_twitter) {
        processer.SharingToSocialMedia("com.twitter.android", context);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_mail){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_map){
        if(!processer.isPermissionGranted(context)){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Hups, niečo je zle :(")
                    .setMessage("Neudelili ste povolenie pre zisťovanie polohy. Vrátime vás na pôvodnu stránku. Pre zapnutie povolenia prejdite do nastavení aplikácie.")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            final Activity innerContext = context;
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(innerContext, MainActivity.class);
                            myIntent.putExtra("website", "http://lodkanadeje.maweb.eu/");
                            innerContext.startActivity(myIntent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Nastavenia", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            final Activity innerContext = context;
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(innerContext, Settings_activity.class);
                            innerContext.startActivity(myIntent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();

        }
        if(processer.isPermissionGranted(context)) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity3.class);
            context.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_instagram){
        processer.SharingToSocialMedia("com.instagram.android", context);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_snapchat){
        processer.SharingToSocialMedia("com.snapchat.android", context);
    }
}
```

So. The problem is that when I use site

> "https://drive.google.com/open?id=redacted"

it just shows me a blank page. I checked almost every solution here on stack, but non of them helped me. When I use

> "http://lodkanadeje.maweb.eu/"

it works perfectly. Somewhere I read that https may be a problem for webview but I don't know if I trust in this :D

Can some of you help me with this problem?

Thanks

PS: the site is in R.id.nav_gallery in MenuProcessing function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the link "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/117iEjf4I" requires a user context.  If it does then you may not able to open the page without setting a user context.

Comment: no that is not the case... I can open page everytime and everywhere... but not in webview in my app